# How to troubleshoot Typeahead and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I have included jQuery 2.1 bootstrap 3.x and the latest typeahead. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var bestPictures = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            prefetch: {
                    url: 'TypeAheadPrefetch.ashx',
                    filter: function (list) {
                        return $.map(list, function (country) { alert(country); return { name: country }; });
                    }
                },
            remote: 'AutoComplete.asmx/GetSuperSearchTypeAhead?q=%QUERY'
        });
        bestPictures.initialize();

        $("#tbSSearch").typeahead(null, {
            name: 'best-pictures',
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: bestPictures.ttAdapter()
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" id="tbSSearch" placeholder="ST Super Search" class="form-control" />
```

The prefetch.ashx returns `["a","b","c"` etc. The prefetched array of strings is so large that it should contain the correct result. So there is no need to call the remote. But it does!! Why is that? And why is there no visible dropdown?

The console of my browser shows an error in the typeahead lib on row 134 col 12 on the `return s.split(/\s+/);`

ps `alert(country);` works

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what GetSuperSearchTypeAhead returns?

Comment: a string array to json (similar to prefetch.ashx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition of "datumTokenizer" try changing "value" to "name" e.g. :

```
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
```

"value" doesn't exist in your list of datums whereas "name" does (see your filter function) so this might be causing the problem.

Similarly change

```
displayKey: 'value',
```

to:

```
displayKey: 'name',
```

I haven't tested this answer as it's always awkward to recreate problems which are using remote/prefetch data calls!